# modifying nginx conf inside docker container returns resource busy

Tags: docker-compose, sed

This is run inside the `docker-compose` **entrypoint** of the original `nginx/latest` docker image.

`sed -i 's/live/staging/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/$$domain.conf`

this command is being run while nginx has not even started yet.
but somehow sed is unable to rename the file.

`nginx -g "daemon off;`

Error logs:

```
cannot rename /etc/nginx/conf.d/sedTTEwyd: Device or resource busy
```

It also creates this temporary file, that it tries to rename, I suppose to overwrite the original file.

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549775/device-or-resource-busy-when-i-try-move-etc-resolv-conf-in-ubuntu18-04-how but different file.